# Visual Code Function "Insert Between Code" ? Is this exist?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

anyone of you coder know about a extension like this?

For example: I have this code multiplied for 100

```php
plan: <?= $this->user->plan_id ?>,
trial: <?= $this->user->plan_trial_done ?>,
email: "<?= $this->user->email ?>",
```

I need to replace
`$this->user->plan_id`
to
`isset($this->user->plan_id) ? $this->user->plan_id : ""`

For example a tool if i select this code: `isset({X}) ? {X} : ""`
Automaticaly replace all `{X}` with the previously selected code?

Comment: How are any of your tags related? What are you talking about, Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? Those are two seperate things

Comment: Sorry, visual studio code.
"How are any of your tags related? " i dont understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a Regex Find-Replace

Find: `(\$this->user->\w+)`

Replace: `isset($1) ? $1 : ""`